# What does the brew master mean by chilling around 30° F (-1°C)?

Tags: fermentation

I'm going to make Frambozen / Raspberry Brown Ale

I was reading [these instructions](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f12/frambozen-clone-recipe-comments-54469/) from the New Belgium Brewing brew master.

He wrote

> Ferment down to 1.014 FG, holding temperatures barely above 68° F. Use a neutral ale yeast (like Wyeast 1056) or a Belgian ale yeast, or even both. After fermentation rack your beer off the yeast and chill it around 30° F if possible.
>
> After 2 weeks of aging, rack your beer (being careful not to transfer any sediment) onto raspberry pulp. This pulp should equal 20%....

What I don't get is about chilling the beer to 30° F.  For how long ?  just for a short period or for full 2 weeks until racking onto the pulp ?  I'm assuming the yeast will go dormant and I'm sure some of the water would freeze.  I don't know what the idea is behind this ?  What if I don't have storage that goes that low, how much of a difference does it make for the finished product ?

Answer (score 3):

Once you reach the final gravity, you can cool down your beer to get the yeast to drop out and clarify the beer.  At 30°F (-1°C), it will probably take 3 days or so.  You'll see it happen.  The beer will not freeze.  It will noticeably clarify your beer, but if you can't do it, don't sweat it.  You can also do it after the beer has been sitting on the fruit instead of before.